# Visual Studio doesn't recognize multi line string

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

When I copy paste multi line strings, from one part of my code to a different part, VS suddenly marks it with all colors of the rainbow starting from the second row (specifically I am changing the functions I use to render content, but it doesn't really matter).

I am just copy pasting the string between two brackets.
This os super annoying, because it forces me to erase all the line breaks so all the text is in one line, which is a complete waste of time. This is the only thing I need to do to "solve" it, It's just an issue with VS, not my code.

Auto formatting all so doesn't work because for VS my code is not valid, so it can't format it. Anyone else ran into this issue before? Any solutions?

Sample code:

```
<div>
    {multipleParagraphs(
      [
        {
          body: "formed from a group
          of international misfits enticed by the weird, wacky and wonderful
          allure of the cultural party experience of",
          items: [""]
        }
      ],
      "paragraph centered-text"
    )}
</div>
```

Comment: As you have *not* provided any sample code, I can only make some broad assumptions about what you *actually* mean! But, if you are talking about **string literals** in C or C++, then you can define these on multiple lines using syntax like: `char buffer[2048] = "abcd" <newline here> "efgh" <newline> "ihkl";` et cetera. But maybe some clarity (and a language tag) would help!

Comment: @AdrianMole I've added a sample. This is a react project. The `body` property is currenty marked with a lot of errors, as the IDE thinks it's code. To "solve" it I have to erase the line drop between all lines so I just have one long line. Nothing to do with the code itself, just the ide.